# Which "Mis---" word is it?

Tags: word-usage

Looking for the word, when someone is talking to someone else about you and tells then you will say something which is actually incorrect. It's "Mis---" something or similar i think - but not "misquote" because it's not actually been said

For instance:

Bob to Jim: Dave will definitely not want to go to that bar

(Dave actually does want to)

Comment: Probably "misguide, mislead."

Comment: Hi Nick, seeking clarification here. The "you" in your question's first sentence maps to "Dave" in your example. What kind of incorrect assertion might Dave make? (NB: in your example, it looks like it's Bob who made the incorrect assertion, not Dave.)

Comment: 'Misinform' comes to mind.

Comment: 'Misconstrue'? . .

Comment: Bob is mistaken. The sentiment is misstated. Dave has been misunderstood.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for might be *misspeak*.  If Bob made a simple mistake, and wasn't intentionally saying an untruth, then *Bob misspoke.*  Or you could say that *Bob gave a misimpression*.

Comment: Maybe "misattributed" but it doesn't quite fit....

Answer (score 2):

***Misrepresent*** would work here.

*to misrepresent --  to give a false or misleading account of the nature of.* [Google Definition](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=misrepresent&spf=1494604497345)

e.g. Bob *misrepresented* Dave's sentiment by claiming Dave would definitely not want to go to that bar.

Some synonyms for misrepresent (same reference as above):
to *skew*, *warp*, *falsify*, *distort*, or *misstate*

Comment: Thanks! it's not the word I was thinking of - it's driving me mad